# Html parse in itextsharp and add it to Paragraph?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, itext

```
Paragraph CommentsofExaminerData = new Paragraph();
if (DTO.QuestionComment != null)
{
    CommentsofExaminerData = new Paragraph(DTO.QuestionComment, fontH2);
}

cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(CommentsofExaminerData));
```

I have html richtextbox value in `DTO.QuestionComment` and i want to convert to html Format.

How can I parse the data?

Comment: new Paragraph(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(DTO.QuestionComment, fontH2));

Can u Try this?

Comment: You Can Strip the Html using this function ::
 private string StripHTML(string input)
        {
            return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty));
        }

it

Comment: it doesnt work in my case

Comment: You want to convert it to Html Or Convert it Fro html ?

Comment: Richtextbox value to normal text

Comment: public string StripHTML(string input) { return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty)); }

This function with do the the work just change the returning type from<string> to what ever u want